# Different behaviour of margins from version 11 to 13

Tags: options

Testing some "11" code on version "13" I noticed an unpleasant difference: the borders of a graph are handled differently.
A simple piece of code that reproduces the problem is

```
y1 = Table[i^2, {i, 10}];
y2 = Table[i, {i, 100}];
SetOptions[{ListLinePlot}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All];
Graphx[1] = ListLinePlot[{y1}];
Graphx[2] = ListLinePlot[{y2}];
Show[GraphicsGrid[{{Graphx[1], Graphx[2]}}], ImageSize -> {1150, 400},
  AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image]
I guess that in version 13 some new option has been added, but I'm unable to fix the problem.
Please help
Thanks

Comment: On my computer with version 13, your code produces the correct result (both plots have a complete border on 100% zoom) but if you zoom out  (60% or 80%) the left plot loses its right border, moreover, on 30%, both plots lose their right border (these number could vary). Maybe it's related to the 2D rendering system that has changed in version 12.3 ([source](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/12/13/new-in-13-core-language/), search DirectWrite) and probably 13.

Answer (score 1):

An old `PlotRange` option  helps:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; y1 = Table[i^2, {i, 10}];
ListLinePlot[{y1}, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {1, 100}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems not enough. Individual plots are ok, but the captions are still struncated.  
  
ClearAll["Global`*"];  
y1 = Table[i^2, {i, 10}];  
y2 = Table[i, {i, 100}];  
SetOptions[{ListLinePlot}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic];  
Graphx[1] = 
  ListLinePlot[{y1}, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {1, 100}}, ImageMargins -> {100}];  
Graphx[2] = 
  ListLinePlot[{y2}, PlotRange -> {{1, 100}, {1, 100}}, ImageMargins -> {100}];  
Show[GraphicsGrid[{{Graphx[1], Graphx[2]}}], ImageSize -> {1150, 400},
  AspectRatio -> Full]  
  
Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, `y1 = Table[i^2, {i, 10}]; y2 = 
 Table[i, {i, 100}]; SetOptions[{ListLinePlot}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]; 
Graphx[1] = 
 ListLinePlot[{y1}, PlotRange -> {{1, 10}, {1, 100}}, 
  ImageMargins -> {100}]; 
Graphx[2] = 
 ListLinePlot[{y2}, PlotRange -> {{1, 100}, {1, 100}}, 
  ImageMargins -> {100}]; Show[GraphicsGrid[{{Graphx[1], Graphx[2]}}],
  ImageSize -> {1150, 400}, AspectRatio -> Full]` OK for me in 13.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: No way. I'm on Windows 11. Thanks for the effort.